# Possible race condition with cursor when using Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In the project that I am working on, built using nodejs & mongo, there is a function that takes in a query and returns set of data based on limit & offset provided to it. Along with this data the function returns a total count stating all the matched objects present in the database. Below is the function:

```
// options carry the limit & offset values
// mongoQuery carries a mongo matching query
function findMany(query, options, collectionId) {
    const cursor = getCursorForCollection(collectionId).find(query, options);
    return Promise.all([findManyQuery(cursor), countMany(cursor)]);
}
```

Now the problem with this is sometime when I give a large limit size I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught exception:  TypeError: Cannot read property '_killCursor' of undefined
```

At first I thought I might have to increase the pool size in order to fix this issue but after digging around a little bit more I was able to find out that the above code is resulting in a race condition. When I changed the code to:

```
function findMany(query, options, collectionId) {
  const cursor = getCursorForCollection(collectionId).find(query, options);
  return findManyQuery(cursor).then((dataSet) => {
    return countMany(cursor).then((count)=> {
      return Promise.resolve([dataSet, count]);
    });
  );
}
```

Everything started working perfectly fine. Now, from what I understand with regard to Promise.all was that it takes an array of promises and resolves them one after the other. If the promises are executed one after the other how can the Promise.all code result in race condition and the chaining of the promises don't result in that.

I am not able to wrap my head around it. Why is this happening?

Comment: "it takes an array of promises and resolves them one after the other." it doesn't do anything to the promises. It creates a new promise that is resolved when all promises are resolved (or rejects if any rejects). Promise resolving is up to the promise instance.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I see. But the promises are resolved one after the other, right? or does it try to resolve all promises at once?
Edit: I think my reference is wrong, what I am trying to say is, it goes through the array provided one by one or does it try to execute all the promises at once?

Comment: `[findManyQuery(cursor), countMany(cursor)]` Both these functions are executed in quick succession, i.e. without the second one waiting for the first one to be resolved. In fact there's nothing in that line of code (--an array with two values returned by two functions) that even knows whether the functions are returning a promise or not.

Comment: "But the promises are resolved one after the other, right?" no why would it be this way? The promises are resolved whenever they want to. Promise.all does not affect individual promises at all. "it try to execute all the promises at once" your mental model of promises is wrong. You are thinking of it as of something executable. But it is just a value (a blackbox that would get the a value some time later or fail to do so). External code probably knows nothing about the blackbox's internal mechanics of getting the value.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Hm. Okay. So it means that both the functions/promises are called at the same time in Promises.all(). What am I trying to ask is, Is there any execution flow that Promise.all follows? We provide it with an array of Promises. When are these promises called? Are these called in quick succession one after the other? Promise.all([1,2,3]). Call 1 -> then call 2 -> then call 3 or would it be like call 1,2,3 all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have very little information to work with, I made an assumption of what you want to achieve and came up with the following using Promise.all() just to demonstrate how you should use Promise.all (which will resolve the array of promises passed to it in no particular order. For this reason, there must be no dependency in any Promise on the order of execution of the Promises. [Read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)).

```
// A simple function to sumulate findManyQuery for demo purposes

function findManyQuery(cursors) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Do your checks and run your code (for example)
        if (cursors) {
            resolve({ dataset: cursors });
        } else {
            reject({ error: 'No cursor in findManyQuery function' });
        }

    });
}


// A simple function to sumulate countMany for demo purposes

function countMany(cursors) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Do your checks and run your code (for example)
        if (cursors) {
            resolve({ count: cursors.length });
        } else {
            reject({ error: 'No cursor in countMany' });
        }
    });
}

// A simple function to sumulate getCursorForCollection for demo purposes

function getCursorForCollection(collectionId) {
   /* 
        Simulating the returned cursor using an array of objects 
        and the Array filter function
    */

    return [{
        id: 1,
        language: 'Javascript',
        collectionId: 99
    }, {
        id: 2,
        language: 'Dart',
        collectionId: 100
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        language: 'Go',
        collectionId: 100
    }, {
        id: 4,
        language: 'Swift',
        collectionId: 99
    }, {
        id: 5,
        language: 'Kotlin',
        collectionId: 101
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        language: 'Python',
        collectionId: 100
    }].filter((row) =>  row.collectionId === collectionId)
}

function findMany(query = { id: 1 }, options = [], collectionId = 0) {

    /*  
         First I create a function to simulate the assumed use of 
         query and options parameters just for demo purposes
     */

    const filterFunction = function (collectionDocument) {
        return collectionDocument.collectionId === query.id && options.indexOf(collectionDocument.language) !== -1;
    };

    /*  
         Since I am working with arrays, I replaced find function 
         with filter function just for demo purposes
     */

    const cursors = getCursorForCollection(collectionId).filter(filterFunction);

    /* 
       Using Promise.all([]). NOTE: You should pass the result of the
       findManyQuery() to countMany() if you want to get the total 
       count of the resulting dataset
    */

    return Promise.all([findManyQuery(cursors), countMany(cursors)]);
}


// Consuming the findMany function with test parameters

const query = { id: 100 };
const collectionId = 100;
const options = ['Javascript', 'Python', 'Go'];

findMany(query, options, collectionId).then(result => {
    console.log(result); // Result would be [ { dataset: [ [Object], [Object] ] }, { count: 2 } ]
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There are ways to write this function in a "pure" way for scalability and testing.

So here's your concern: 
*In the project that I am working on, built using nodejs & mongo, there is a function that takes in a query and returns set of data based on limit & offset provided to it. Along with this data the function returns a total count stating all the matched objects present in the database.*

**Note**: You'll need to take care of edge case.

```
const Model = require('path/to/model');

function findManyUsingPromise(model, query = {}, offset = 0, limit = 10) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        model.find(query, (error, data) => {
            if(error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            resolve({
                data,
                total: data.length || 0
            });
        }).skip(offset).limit(limit);
    });

}

// Call function

findManyUsingPromise(Model, {}, 0, 40).then((result) => {
    // Do something with result  {data: [object array], total: value }
}).catch((err) => {
    // Do something with the error
});
```

Comment: You cannot `return` from a callback

Comment: But your answer doesn't mention why the Promise.all() doesn't work. You just posted a function  that is basically doing what I am doing as per my solution which works.
Also, data would be an array of limited(taking in the limit) objects matching the query but the totalCount that I get is the total objects present in the DB matching the query without limit.

Comment: hi @abhinav I have posted another reply addressing the use of Promise.all(). Knowing what's going on in your other functions will be helping in resolving the concerns you have.